# im.paste() returning None?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def changeImage(event,label,images,image):
    w = event.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    x,y = image.size
    thumbed = images[index].resize((x,y),PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    print str(thumbed)
    tup = (0,0,x,y)
    paste = image.paste(thumbed,tup)
    final = ImageTk.PhotoImage(paste)
    label.config(image=final)
    label.image = final
```

I've been doing some debugging and the only thing wrong here is that the paste variable turns out to be None for some reason and I can't figure out why. It throws this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Exception AttributeError: "'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'" in <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x000000000A4C7208>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Alec\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.1.3253.win-x86_64\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Alec\Desktop\Bhimisti Frames Software\Bhimisti_Frames-ver3.py", line 62, in <lambda>
frames.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", lambda event,arg=imLabel,arg2=images,arg3=image: changeImage(event,arg,arg2,arg3))
File "C:\Users\Alec\Desktop\Bhimisti Frames Software\Bhimisti_Frames-ver3.py", line 35, in changeImage
final = ImageTk.PhotoImage(paste)
File "C:\Users\Alec\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 108, in __init__
mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
File "C:\Users\Alec\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 297, in getmodebase
return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
File "C:\Users\Alec\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageMode.py", line 52, in getmode
return _modes[mode]
KeyError: None
```

Comment: Are you sure that `paste` is _supposed_ to return something? Maybe it modifies the image in-place? When you use `help(ImageTk.PhotoImage.paste)`, note that there is no hint of the method returning anything.

Comment: I think you could do this without `paste` - directly `PhotoImage(thumbed)`

Comment: I suspect OP replaces full image - I think OP resizes `thumbed` to fit `image`. btw: `picture-in-picture` sounds interesting :)

Comment: @furas Guess you are right. `x, y` is the size of the image, so it will be 100% covered with the pasted "thumb". At first I thought `image` is the one being shrunk, but that's `images[index]`

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you so much this fixed it

Comment: I edited to indent function body, assuming that everything after first line is part of body.  Please verify that now correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paste` method does indeed return nothing but instead alters the picture in-place. See e.g. [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm) and [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/image-tk.html). You could change your code to this:

```
image.paste(thumbed,tup)           # nothing is returned, so no assignment
final = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)  # using image instead of pasted
```

Of course, this means that your `image` will be changed, so you might want to create a copy before pasting.

Also, as pointed out by @furas, it seems that you do not need to paste at all: You resize `image[index]` to the same size as `image`, and then paste it into `image`, spanning its entire size. Instead, you should be able to use the resized picture directly.

```
thumbed = images[index].resize((x,y), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
final = ImageTk.PhotoImage(thumbed)
```

This, however, will *not* change `image`, so if you want to change it, you have to paste.